# Save a list of dist objects to table in R

Tags: r, matrix, export, distance

i need to create a file with multiple distance matrices separated with an empty line.
The output should look like this:

```
# First matrix
0.05194497                                                       
0.04652118 0.12935323                                            
0.04269506 0.09953116 0.08464824                                 
         NA         NA         NA         NA                      
0.02884847 0.07769535 0.05385956 0.04588298         NA           
0.03821721 0.12084543 0.13431270 0.06928795         NA 0.05123967
# Empty line

# Second matrix
0.05194497                                                       
0.04652118 0.12935323                                            
0.04269506 0.09953116 0.08464824                                 
        NA         NA         NA         NA                      
0.02884847 0.07769535 0.05385956 0.04588298         NA           
0.03821721 0.12084543 0.13431270 0.06928795         NA 0.05123967
```

I have like 100 distance matrixes in a list in R and i need to export them to a txt-file as shown in the above example. Anyone has an idea how to do this? I need a single file and not multiple txt-files.

Comment: To clarify: you don't want row names and column names in the output, correct? And is your list a named list?

Comment: yes, correct. Pure values. The order of the rows/columns determines their identity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one option using `sink`, `lapply`, and `dput`. In order to use `write.table` on a `dist` object, it needs to be a matrix, so in the `lapply` step, we convert it to a matrix, then manually set the diagonal and upper triangle to `NA` before writing our output.

Here is some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 5)
y <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 5)
myList <- list(A = dist(x),
               B = dist(y))
myList
# $A
#          1        2        3        4
# 2 5.701817                           
# 3 6.013119 5.032069                  
# 4 7.276905 5.325473 5.811861         
# 5 6.619295 5.306750 4.945987 6.612081
# 
# $B
#          1        2        3        4
# 2 7.469565                           
# 3 5.717330 6.407709                  
# 4 5.371346 6.106838 5.057519         
# 5 6.029762 6.256703 4.685266 5.452838
```

Here's how you can write the output to a file with some blank lines in between. There is also a line `NULL` after each matrix has been printed that could easily be removed.

```
sink("myDistList.txt", type="output")
invisible(
  lapply(myList, function(x) { 
    y <- as.matrix(x)
    y[upper.tri(y)] <- NA
    diag(y) <- NA
    dput(write.table(y, row.names = FALSE,
                     col.names = FALSE, na = ""))
  cat("\n\n")
  }))
sink()
```

Opening up "myDistList.txt" should give you something that looks like this:

```
5.70181650842794    
6.01311946994002 5.03206860827638   
7.27690516432265 5.32547302778382 5.8118611864786  
6.61929500038789 5.3067497799772 4.94598733972826 6.61208111472781 
NULL



7.46956498920544    
5.7173301814994 6.40770896281359   
5.37134559156135 6.10683846835378 5.05751911328028  
6.02976206855185 6.25670324709768 4.68526645722475 5.45283785882534 
NULL
```

---

Of course, `capture.output(myList, file = "myDistList.txt")` would also get you *very* close to your desired output--but it would be just as if you printed `myList` to screen (that is, it will include row and column names). Some clever regex work should be able to remove the extra lines easily though, if you decide to go that route.

For example, using "[geany](http://www.geany.org/)" as my text editor for the output of `capture.output`, I was able to clean up the text file with the following search-and-replace options (with "Use regular expressions" selected, of course):

1. Search for `^\s+.*|^\$.*` and replace with a single space
2. Search for `^[0-9]+\s(.*)` and replace with `\1`

In a way, I prefer this method to having to go back through and convert the distance matrix to a matrix and so on.